# Login to another website on click of button on my website

Tags: java, php, redirect, curl, authentication

I have a requirement to create a button on my website which can be accessed by all logged in users.
This button will login to other website using stored credentials. It means all users will login to other website with same login credentials.

I searched for the solutions. I could only find `curl` in php and `URLConnection` in Java. But how much I read, it seems that curl and urlconnection can only read the data from other website. But I need to redirect to other website after clicking the button on my website.

Please tell me is there a way to do this.

I also tried iframe to take control of other website login page but that didn't work. Their website is on https.

Answer (score 2):

You can Use the Localstorage for the web browser , so you can check if localstorage values

```
     //logged IN 
    if (!localStorage.userid || localStorage.userid == '') {

       //show you button;
    }else { //hide you button }
```

but you must have control for the other website to check the credentials or logged status.

Comment: The main question is how can i log in to other website on just click of button on my website

Comment: kindly give more clear details about your both sites , are you controlling the both sites ??

Comment: No only one site, the other site is another portal accessible on our intranet but owned by another department

Comment: you must arrange with them to let you use some api or web service , simple from your side you can , you can store the credentials in the localstorage and every time you want to access the button you will use them to submit to the web service that links to other site.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
response.sendRedirect("https://otherwebsite.com/login?username=user&pwd=password");
```

For security reason this is generally not the best idea. 
Another way would be to send a form with hidden fields (over https so the data is encrypted) with an autosubmit to the otherwebsite.com.

Comment: The main question is how can i log in to other website on just click of button on my website

Comment: The click on the button sends a request to the server. The server sends a page with the credentials as hidden fields in a form. The action of the form calls the login function of the otherwebsite and is set to autosubmit. So when the browser loads this form it is submitted and logs in to th otherwebsite.

Comment: password is sent via POST. Appending in URL won't work

Comment: So you must use a form like this:  <form name="loginForm" method="post" action="https://otherwebsite.com/login" >...</form> and some JavaScript for autosubmit: <script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function () {
var act = function(){document.loginForm.submit()};
window.setTimeout(act, 500/* timeout in miliseconds */);
}